# split up an array of dates into consecutive date arrays

Tags: php, arrays, date

i have a array of dates that looks something like this:

```
Array (
  [0] => 08/20/2013
  [1] => 08/21/2013
  [2] => 08/22/2013
  [3] => 08/23/2013
  [4] => 08/26/2013
)
```

it's always going to be different depending on the dates the user selects but for example lets use this one.

what i need to do is figure out a way to separate the array into consecutive dates and non consecutive dates.

so in the end i should have something like:

```
Array (
  [0] => 08/20/2013
  [1] => 08/21/2013
  [2] => 08/22/2013
  [3] => 08/23/2013
)

Array ([4] => 08/26/2013)
```

i should specify that it's not only two arrays. non consecutive dates would each have their own array, and consecutive dates would each be in their own array.

Comment: Just a foreach loop, if current date = laste date + 1, add to current stack, otherwise, add current stack to result array & start a new stack.

Comment: Did you want the result to be date_array[][], which date_array[x][] will contain all consecutive dates and which date_array[y][] will contain another group? Using a loop is a good idea. And compare current one with the last one.

Comment: what do i check the first date against?

Comment: Just use for (var i = 0; i < count(array); i++) and use if (i == 0) to escape the first element checks.

Comment: If you use foreach, you can set an is_first = true outside the foreach loop and in the loop use if (is_first) to escape the very first loop and then set is_first to false.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `$arr` to represent your array:

```
usort($arr, function ($a, $b){
    return strtotime($a) - strtotime($b);
});
$out = array();
$last = 0;
$dex = -1;
foreach ($arr as $key => $value){
    $current = strtotime($value);
    if ($current - $last > 86400) $dex++;
    $out[$dex][] = $value;
    $last = $current;
}
print_r($out);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 08/20/2013
            [1] => 08/21/2013
            [2] => 08/22/2013
            [3] => 08/23/2013
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 08/26/2013
        )

)
```